# 3D on Bing maps

Tags: ajax, 3d, bing

Are there  ways to get a 3D model 
(maybe made by a tool like 3DVIA at)
into a 3D Bing map.

I tried following the steps at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc451896.aspx
under the heading 3DVIA and I can't find the options mentioned.

If there is a way to import 3D models on the fly it would be great?

I'm trying to do this using the SDK at
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps 3d Control has been retired so there is currently no supported 3d mode at all in Bing Maps